# How to ensure that string interpolated into `sed` substitution escapes all metachars

Tags: sed, quoting

I have a script that reads a text stream and generates a file of sed commands that is later run with `sed -f`. The generated sed commands are like:

```
s/cid:image002\.gif@01CC3D46\.926E77E0/https:\/\/mysite.com\/files\/1922/g
s/cid:image003\.gif@01CC3D46\.926E77E0/https:\/\/mysite.com\/files\/1923/g
s/cid:image004\.jpg@01CC3D46\.926E77E0/https:\/\/mysite.com\/files\/1924/g
```

Assume the script which generates the `sed` commands is something like:

```
while read cid fileid
do
    cidpat="$(echo $cid | sed -e s/\\./\\\\./g)"
    echo 's/'"$cidpat"'/https:\/\/mysite.com\/files\/'"$fileid"'/g' >> sedscr
done
```

How can I improve the script to ensure all regex metacharacters in the `cid` string are escaped and interpolated properly?

Comment: See [is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To escape variables to be used on the *left hand side* and *right hand side* of a `s` command in `sed` (here `$lhs` and `$rhs` respectively), you'd do:

```
escaped_lhs=$(printf '%s\n' "$lhs" | sed 's:[][\\/.^$*]:\\&:g')
escaped_rhs=$(printf '%s\n' "$rhs" | sed 's:[\\/&]:\\&:g; $!s/$/\\/')

sed "s/$escaped_lhs/$escaped_rhs/"
```

Note that `$lhs` cannot contain a newline character.

That is, on the LHS, escape all the regexp operators (`][.^$*`), the escaping character itself (`\`, and the separator (`/`).

On the RHS, you only need to escape `&`, the separator, backslash and the newline character (which you do by inserting a backslash at the end of each line except the last one (`$!s/$/\\/`)).

Note: you don't want to add backslashes before characters that do *not* have a special meaning, because in doing so, you could end up *giving* them a special meaning. For instance, `<`, `+` and `t` have no special meaning in BREs, but `\<`, `\+` and `\t` do in some implementations of `sed` (and for `\t`, including on the RHS).

That assumes you use `/` as a separator in your `sed` `s` commands and that you don't enable *Extended REs* with `-r` (GNU `sed`/`ssed`/`ast`/`busybox sed`) or `-E` (BSDs, `ast`, recent GNU, recent busybox) or *PCREs* with `-R` (`ssed`) or *Augmented REs* with `-A`/`-X` (`ast`) which all have extra RE operators.

For EREs, the most widely supported of those extensions, the equivalent would be:

```
escaped_lhs=$(printf '%s\n' "$lhs" | sed 's:[][\\/.^$*+?(){}|]:\\&:g')
escaped_rhs=$(printf '%s\n' "$rhs" | sed 's:[\\/&]:\\&:g; $!s/$/\\/')

sed -E "s/$escaped_lhs/$escaped_rhs/"
```

A few ground rules when dealing with arbitrary data:

- [Don't use `echo`](/q/65803)
- [quote your variables](/q/171346)
- consider the impact of the locale (especially its character set: it's important that the *escaping* `sed` commands are run in the same locale as the `sed` command *using* the *escaped* strings (and with the same `sed` command) for instance)
- don't forget about the newline character (here you may want to check if `$lhs` contains any and take action).

A much safer option is to use `perl` instead of `sed` and pass the strings in the environment and use the `\Q`/`\E` `perl` regexp operators for taking strings literally:

```
A="$lhs" B="$rhs" perl -pe 's/\Q$ENV{A}\E/$ENV{B}/g'
```

`perl` (by default) will not be affected by the locale's character set as, in the above, it only considers the strings as arrays of bytes without caring about what characters (if any) they may represent for the user. With `sed`, you could achieve the same by fixing the locale to `C` with `LC_ALL=C` for all `sed` commands (though that will also affect the language of error messages, if any).

In some shells, you can also do the escaping without having to resort to external utilities.

In `zsh` (here for BRE escaping):

```
set -o extendedglob
escaped_lhs=${lhs//(#m)[][\\.^$\/&]/\\$MATCH}
escaped_rhs=${rhs//(#m)[\\&\/$'\n']/\\$MATCH}
```

In `ksh93`:

```
escaped_lhs=${lhs//[][\\.^$\/&]/\\\0}
escaped_rhs=${rhs//[\\&\/$'\n']/\\\0}
```

In `fish` 3.4.0+:

```
set escaped_lhs (
  string replace -ar -- '[][\\\\/.^$*]' '\\\\$0' "$lhs" |
    string collect --allow-empty
)

set escaped_rhs (
  string replace -ar -- '[\\\\&/'\n']' '\\\\$0' "$rhs" |
    string collect --allow-empty --no-trim-newlines
)
```

Comment: What if I need to escape double quotes?

Comment: @Menon, double quotes are not special to `sed`, you don't need to escape them.

Comment: This cannot be used for pattern matching using wildcard, can it?

Comment: @Menon, no, wildcard pattern matching as with `find`'s `-name` is different from  regular expressions. There you only need to escape `?`, `*` backslash and `[`

Comment: With my present version of Bash 5.2.15 it is also possible to do the escaping without external utilities (and without requiring `shopt -s extglob`). This is 8 years after your answer, so maybe it's newly possible due to a functional change in Bash since then. This works for me => `escaped_lhs="${lhs//[][\\\/.^\$*]/\\&}"; escaped_rhs="${rhs//[\\\/&$'\n']/\\&}"; escaped_rhs="${escaped_rhs%\\$'\n'}"$'\n'`