# Delete lines from a file using awk or sed based on the variable from previous command

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a CSV file (say temp.csv) with strings and numbers. I need to delete the lines which contain a particular pattern of string at the beginning of the lines in the file. For example, here is my file -

```
req1,incl_patt1,excl_patt1,2,ind1
req1,incl_patt2,excl_patt2,1,ind1
req1,incl_patt3,excl_patt3,4,ind1
req2,inc_patt1,exc_patt1,1,ind2
req2,inc_patt2,exc_patt2,2,ind2
req2,inc_patt3,exc_patt3,3,ind2
req3,pattern3,expatt3,1,ind3
req4,pattern4,expatt4,1,ind4
```

I am writing a pattern to `req_file_curr` in a command 
`~ $ req_file_curr=req1`

`echo "${req_file_curr}"` gives output as `req1`

However when using it in a **`sed`** command, like below:

```
sed '/\"${req_file_curr}\"/d' temp.csv
```

gives output as

```
req1,incl_patt1,excl_patt1,2,ind1
req1,incl_patt2,excl_patt2,1,ind1
req1,incl_patt3,excl_patt3,4,ind1
req2,inc_patt1,exc_patt1,1,ind2
req2,inc_patt2,exc_patt2,2,ind2
req2,inc_patt3,exc_patt3,3,ind2
req3,pattern3,expatt3,1,ind3
req4,pattern4,expatt4,1,ind4
```

I am expeceting the output as

```
req2,inc_patt1,exc_patt1,1,ind2
req2,inc_patt2,exc_patt2,2,ind2
req2,inc_patt3,exc_patt3,3,ind2
req3,pattern3,expatt3,1,ind3
req4,pattern4,expatt4,1,ind4
```

How can I use the variable from a shell as a pattern to look for in **`sed`** or **`awk`**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to enclose the `sed` pattern in double quotes so that the shell can expand the variable before passing it to `sed`:

```
sed "/^${req_file}/d" temp.csv
```

You also need to use the `^` anchor to indicate to `sed` that this pattern needs to occur at the beginning of the line.

Comment: +1 and Thank you for explaining the use of `^` anchor.

Answer (score 5):

No need for `awk` or `sed` here:

```
grep -v "^$req_file_curr," file
```

Note that (like for `sed` or `awk` though to a lesser extent), that assumes that `$req_file_curr` does not contain regexp operators (like `.`, `*`...).

If it does, you'd have to escape those characters, or with `awk`, you could use an approach using its `index()` function:

```
S="$req_file_curr," awk 'index($0, ENVIRON["S"]) != 1' < file
```

Comment: I tried to append `.req` to the contents of first columns to check if `sed` or `awk` works, it actually works fine with the code provided by @joseph. `req_file_curr=req1.req`. Using the sed command as provided above `sed "/^${req_file}/d" temp.csv` gives exactly what I need. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: @Dhruuv, `.` matches any character, so `req1.req` would match `req1.req` but also `req12req` or `req1,req`.

Comment: I do have `.` in the first column of my file. I am leaning more towards `sed` because I can use inplace edit option `sed -i` (which I learned recently) instead of streaming the output into a file and then renaming that file to the original file name. Is there a way to handle the regexp operators while using `sed`? Otherwise, I will have to go ahead with `grep`

Comment: @Dhruuv See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129063/22565 (escape as per the LHS)

Comment: grep also does regular expressions. awk has an index() function that compares actual strings, not using patterns.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant, good point thanks. I've added an `index()`-based appraoch.

Answer (score 4):

You have set `req_file_curr` but use `req_file`. And your `sed` command won't work, since shell variable can not be expanded in your `sed` command.

You can try this:

```
$ sed '/'"${req_file_curr}"'/d' file
req2,inc_patt1,exc_patt1,1,ind2
req2,inc_patt2,exc_patt2,2,ind2
req2,inc_patt3,exc_patt3,3,ind2
req3,pattern3,expatt3,1,ind3
req4,pattern4,expatt4,1,ind4
```

or using `sed` with double quote:

```
sed "/${req_file_curr}/d" file
```

and using `awk`:

```
$ awk -v req=$req_file_curr '$0 !~ req' file
req2,inc_patt1,exc_patt1,1,ind2
req2,inc_patt2,exc_patt2,2,ind2
req2,inc_patt3,exc_patt3,3,ind2
req3,pattern3,expatt3,1,ind3
req4,pattern4,expatt4,1,ind4
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing the mistake in my question, I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

An ed solution would be something like.

```
  req_file_curr=req1

  printf '%s\n' "g/^$req_file_curr/d"  w | ed -s temp.csv
```

It edit's the file inplace so test first before running this against your files.