# What characters should I escape while modifying a file using sed?

Tags: bash, sed, regular-expression

I am using the following sed command(with word boundary):

```
sed "7 s/\<<Filevalue=.*/>\>/<Filevalue="true"/>/" < config.xml
```

And I am getting this error:

```
sed: command garbled: 7 s/\<<Filevalue=.*/>\>/<Filevalue="true"/>/
```

I tried escaping special characters but still getting same error:

```
sed "7 s/\<\<Filevalue=.*\/\/\>\>/\<Filevalue=\"true\"\/\>/" < config.xml
```

What have I done wrong?

EDIT:

This is a dummy XML. Values of Filevalue may vary.

XML Content:

```
<Filevalue="false">
<Filevalue="false">
<Filevalue="false">
<Filevalue="false">
<Filevalue="false">
<Filevalue="false">
<Filevalue="false">
```

Comment: Can you quote the snippet out of your `config.xml`. That doesn't look like valid XML?

Comment: I dont think this has anything to do with the XML. Its just a dummy xml I created for testing.

Comment: Point is pretty inherently, XML is a data format that is not well suited to regex parsing. But XML parsers can do it very easily.

Comment: OK, thanks for including it. That isn't valid XML.  I'd suggest that you're going down the wrong road using it in your 'dummy XML' file.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/129059

Comment: @Sobrique, I know this is not a well formatted xml. But I am using sed command and not any XML parser which is why I said the error is not related to XML format. I cannot use XML parser here hence I have to stick with regex. So, can you point out what has caused the error?

Answer (score 1):

You have to backslash the slashes that don't work as separators, too, or use a different separator:

```
sed "7 s%\<<Filevalue=.*/>\>%<Filevalue="true"/>%"
```

Also, you can't include double quotes in double quotes without backslashing them, or switch to single quotes.

Moreover, a word can't start with a `<`, so `\<<` never matches.

Comment: `sed '7{/Filevalue=/s%=[^/]*%="true"%'`

Comment: @choroba I think I have backslashed all the slashes in the question.

Comment: @Menon: Not in the first line.

Comment: @choroba Please look at third expression. Still got error.

Comment: What OS, what sed version?

Comment: Release: 5.10
Kernel architecture: sun4v
Kernel version: SunOS 5.10 Generic_147147-26
                               OpenWindows version:
Solaris X11 Version 6.6.2 19 November 2010

Answer (score 1):

What you have done wrong is you're trying to parse XML with a regular expression. This is a bad idea - it sometimes works, but it makes brittle code. XML has a specification that allows for linefeeds, whitespace and tag nesting - all things that regex handle very badly.

The real answer is 'use a parser'.

I would suggest `perl` and `XML::Twig` as options - there are others though:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    'pretty_print'  => 'indented',
    'twig_handlers' => {
        'File' => sub { $_->set_att( 'value', 'true' ) }
    }
);

$twig->parsefile('config.xml');    
$twig->print;
```

I have made certain assumptions about the content of your XML - if you're prepared to give a more extensive example, I'll double check and make sure this works as indented.

Edit:

Based on the snippet you posted - that isn't valid XML, so disregard the above. I would still suggest though that you don't use something that looks a bit like XML, called `output.xml` because that's a road to all sorts of pain and woe.

My code above will work with:

```
<xml>
   <File value="false"/>
   <File value="false"/>
   <File value="false"/>
   <File value="false"/>
   <File value="false"/>
   <File value="false"/>
   <File value="false"/> 
</xml>
```

You can check XML validity here: http://www.xmlvalidation.com/index.php?id=1&L=0

If we leave aside the fact that it's not XML - this works:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    #amend just line 7
   if ( $. == 7 ) { s,<Filevalue=".*">,<Filevalue="true">,; }
   print;
}
__DATA__
<Filevalue="false">
<Filevalue="false">
<Filevalue="false">
<Filevalue="false">
<Filevalue="false">
<Filevalue="false">
<Filevalue="false">
```

Which you can one-liner by:

```
perl -nle 'if ( $.==7) {s,<Filevalue=".*">,<Filevalue="true">,g;} print;' notxml.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

choroba is mostly right ... but he's misleading about the double-quotes: that's not a problem for sed, but it is for the shell.

You only need to escape `* [ ] \ .` and the delimiter (by default `/`). In your case, I believe this would work best:

```
sed '7s%<<\([^>]*\)>>%<\1>%' file
```

If it works, use the `-i` option to replace it in the file.

Explanation:

- The `\( \)` group an expression and is replaced on the right-hand-side with `\`
- The `[^>]*` gobbles up all the characters until the next right-angle-bracket.
- So anything within the incorrect double-brackets will be replaced with the same expression within one. Note, this will happen only *once* on line 7 unless you append the `g` flag to the `s` command.