# Replacing variable containing \ with sed

Tags: linux, shell-script, sed, replace

i am trying to replace `$old`  string with `$new` string in file where:

```
old=ESX_10.1.1.1\@11.11.11.11
new=host_15_11_0_111.static
```

I am using sed command:

```
sed i "s/${old}/${new}/g" /filename
```

but it does not replace the word and also not shows any error.
I have tried it with many ways, like replacing:

```
sed i "s,${old},${new},g" /filename
```

and

```
sed i "s=${old}=${new}=g" /filename
```

but it does not work.
Help me to solve this

Comment: See [How to ensure that string interpolated into \`sed\` substitution escapes all metachars](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129063)

Comment: 1. Did you really mean `sed i` or is that a typo for `sed -i`? 2. Did you have write access to `/` to create a temporary file and then rename it as `/filename`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `\` with another `\`. You can do this in a bash shell variable as follows

```
sed -i -e "s/${old//\\/\\\\}/${new//\\/\\\\}/g" filename
```

See `man bash` *Parameter Expansion* for `${parameter/pattern/string}`. We use the version with `//` instead of `/` to do it repeatedly. And we need to escape `\` with itself, so it gets duplicated a lot.

Comment: `"s/${old//\\/\\\\}/${new}/g"` should work too as in this case `new` variable doesn't have backslashes to escape

Comment: Hi tried with s/${old//\\/\\\\}/${new}/g but it gives error,"sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unterminated `s' command"

Comment: Note you must be using `bash` as your shell. You can add `set -x` to the start of the script so you can see what strings are actually being  used. You must the double-quote char `"` as shown in the sed, and also when setting your variable `old="ESX_10.1.1.1\@11.11.11.11"`.