# Add something to crontab programmatically (over ssh)

Tags: scripting, cron

I have a deployment script. 
It must add something to a user `crontab`
(trigger a script that cleans logs every *XXX* days);
however, this must be done only during the first deployment,
or when it needs to be updated.

(I can run `xxx.py deploy env` or `xxx.py update env`.)

so I need to do this:

> Check if my cronJob already exists 
> Submit my cronJob if it does not already exist 
> or 
> update my cronJob if one of the parameter(s) of the command is different

I don't see how to add/check/remove something to the `crontab`
without using `crontab -e` or "manually" editing the `crontab` file
(download it, rewrite it, re-upload it).

PS: this is a user specific cronjob;
"webadmin" is going to do it and he should not use `sudo` to do it.

Comment: Does it have to be in a user-specific crontab? Most prepackaged cron jobs go into one of the /etc/cron.\* directories.

Comment: Does CentOS have `/etc/cron.d`? If so, put your script in there using a name unique to your application

Comment: yes it's user specific. I can't add it to /etc/cron.d because it's a root file, thus only root's job are alowed inside (I could sudo but that a bad practice I've been told)

Comment: same as `/etc/crontab`, files in `/etc/cron.d/` have an extra field for the username, immediately after the schedule spec.   e.g. `* * * * * username /path/to/script`.   See `man 5 crontab` and search for `SYSTEM CRON`.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610839/how-can-i-programmatically-create-a-new-cron-job/49886076#49886076

Comment: Related: [How do I add/remove cron jobs by script?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/363376)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### My best idea so far

To check first if the content matches what should be in there and only update if it doesn't:

```
if [[ $(crontab -l | egrep -v "^(#|$)" | grep -q 'some_command'; echo $?) == 1 ]]
then
    set -f
    echo $(crontab -l ; echo '* 1 * * * some_command') | crontab -
    set +f
fi
```

but this gets complicated enough to build a separate script around that cron task.

#### Other ideas

You could send the string via stdin to crontab (beware, this clears out any previous crontab entries):

```
echo "* 1 * * * some_command" | crontab -
```

This should even work right through ssh:

```
echo "* 1 * * * some_command" | ssh user@host "crontab -"
```

if you want to append to the file you could use this:

```
# on the machine itself
echo "$(echo '* 1 * * * some_command' ; crontab -l 2>&1)" | crontab -
# via ssh
echo "$(echo '* 1 * * * some_command' ; ssh user@host crontab -l 2>&1)" | ssh user@host "crontab -"
```

Comment: that depends: do you need what would have been in there? :)

Comment: awww ... not running as root? ... I'll rewrite it ...

Comment: eh, I like that :D

Comment: I had two issues with this solution: 1) `echo '*...` expanded the `*` to a list of files. 2) the line endings in the crontab got deleted.

Comment: I was able to fix these issues by: 1) change to `echo "*...` and 2) remove `echo $` from the start of the line.

Comment: See my answer further down for a working fix to the `*` (wildcard) expansion issue.

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann: You're missing quotes in the version of "my best idea so far". It should be `echo "$(crontab -l ; echo '* 1 * * * some_command')" | crontab -`

Comment: I incorporated the suggestion from @YngvarKristiansen , thanks for the hint about `set -f`

Comment: your answer puts all the crontabs in a single line, so it doesnt work

Comment: @CompEng88 see the answer provided by Yngar Kristiansen below which fixes the line issue.

Answer (score 7):

For the record I'm going to suggest using `/etc/cron.d/`. Only root can write files here but the entries can be configured to run as any user (without need for `sudo` at run-time). This example defines the task named `my_webadmin` that will execute `/usr/local/bin/tidy_logfiles` as the user `webadmin` every Sunday at midnight:

```
echo '0 0 * * 0 webadmin /usr/local/bin/tidy_logfiles' >/etc/cron.d/my_webadmin
```

An important part is that the `my_webadmin` should be unique to you (not necessarily unique for the run, though) because any installation package can also write files here and you want to avoid a clash. Having this uniqueness constraint, you can update `my_webadmin` with a simple overwrite, since you know it's "yours" and won't contain entries for anyone/anything else.

Furthermore, with this approach it becomes trivial to remove the cron entry

```
rm -f /etc/cron.d/my_webadmin
```

---

Possibly outside the scope of your question, but if you have remote access to the root account (or via `sudo`) you can even provision remotely,

```
echo '0 0 * * 0 webadmin /usr/local/bin/tidy_logfiles' > ~/webadmin.cron
scp -p ~/webadmin.cron root@remote_host:/etc/cron.d/my_webadmin
```

or,

```
echo '0 0 * * 0 webadmin /usr/local/bin/tidy_logfiles' |
    ssh -q root@remote_host 'cat >/etc/cron.d/my_webadmin'
```

and remove the provisioning,

```
ssh -nq root@remote_host rm -f /etc/cron.d/my_webadmin
```

(Note that in many cases you cannot provide root's password for the `scp`/`ssh` commands because the root account is constrained to prevent password-based logins. Instead you need to have set up public/private key certificates. Also, by implication the local account (whatever it is) will have full root access to the remote server.)

Comment: It's my client server, I cannot log as root, I can sudo into it BUT, if I do that they'll kill me.

This is a webadlmin job so it should only be in the webadmin stuff, that's what the sysadmin told me.

Comment: @sliders_alpha the job only runs as webadmin. It's the provisioning that requires root equivalence. However, I'll look for a non-root solution too.

Comment: +1. `/etc/cron.d/` exists for exactly this purpose - so that packages / deployments can just drop a crontab file in here.

Comment: cas and roaima are spot on. this is why /etc/cron.d/ exists -- so you can "install" a crontab for a specific app without having to append / detect anything

Comment: Is there a way to make cronjobs put in `/etc/cron.d/somefile` show up in a (non-root) user's `crontab -l`? How do I make it so that those jobs are "for a specific user"? You mention, that it is possible to configure the jobs in `/etc/cron.d/` to run without root. How?

Comment: @ZelphirKaltstahl (a) no, (b) I've updated the answer (first paragraph) to reference the username field of this system crontab file, (c) the example I gave runs without root

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend using Ansible* for this rather than rolling your own. Or Puppet or Chef — but Ansible is well-suited for zero-infrastructure deploy scripts like this.

That's because there are already modules meant to solve problems like this, and config management tools have have [idempotence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) as a basic design goal — that's the property of only changing when it needs to even if you accidentally (or intentionally) run it again.

In particular, Ansible's [cron module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/cron_module.html) can modify user crontabs. As a bonus, if you want to later adjust to use system crontabs, it'll be a very easy tweak rather than a rewrite.

---

* disclaimer: I work for Red Hat, and Ansible is a Red Hat sponsored project.

Comment: Yup, thing is, I didn't knew about ansible 2 month ago, and now we have a massive python deployer script (but he is MAGNIFICIENT, readable, maintanable, ;)) 

Next time, I'll use ansible but right now going back is impossible (money money money)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a cron job via the target account, run `crontab -e`. This command passes the crontab through an editor. Tell it to use an editor command that modifies the crontab as you desire. The editor command is executed as a shell snippet with the name of a temporary file appended.

```
unset VISUAL
EDITOR='update_crontab () {
  set -e
  new=$(mktemp)
  if <"$1" grep -v "^#" | grep -w do_stuff; then
    # Remove existing entries containing do_stuff
    grep -v -w do_stuff "$1" >"$new"
  else
    cp "$1" "$new"
  fi
  # Add the new entry
  echo "1 2 3 4 5 do_stuff --new-options" >>"$new"
  mv "$new" "$1"
}
update_crontab' crontab -e
```

This approach is more reliable than the native `crontab -l | … | crontab -` because this one is vulnerable to a race condition if the crontab is edited concurrently: modifications made between the call to `crontab -l` and the call to `crontab -` would be undone.

Answer (score 2):

This is an adaptation of what [@phillip-zyan-k-lee-stockmann](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/179932/phillip-zyan-k-lee-stockmann) offered, based on his "Best idea so far" code.

My changes from his (excellent and helpful snippet) are basically:

- Regex for not just the command name, but also the whole entry including time strings. That way it could support adding a command even if there are same-named or overlapping-named commands in other entries. (It still won't add the same command on the same schedule twice.)
- A bit of logging
- I switched (and named) mine to hourly for various reasons; easy to adjust it back per crontab syntax

And so here's my code for what I called `crontab-add-hourly.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# PURPOSE:
# To allow simple, programmatic addition of commands/entries into the crontab (if not already present)

cmd=$1
entry="0 * * * * $cmd"
printf "we want to add this entry:\n$entry\n\n" 
escapedEntry=$(printf '%s\n' "$entry" | sed 's:[][\/.^$*]:\\&:g') #from: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129063/320236
printf "but first we'll see if it's already in there using this regex pattern:\n$escapedEntry\n\n"

if [[ $(crontab -l | egrep -v '^(#|$)' | grep -q "$escapedEntry"; echo $?) == 1 ]] # from: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/297377/320236
then
    printf "all clear; pattern was not already present; adding command to crontab hourly:\n$cmd\n\n"
    (crontab -l ; printf "$entry\n\n") | crontab -
else
    printf "pattern already present; no action taken\n\n"
fi
```

Example usage and output:

```
$ ./crontab-add-hourly.sh my-script.bash

we want to add this entry:
0 * * * * my-script.bash

but first we'll see if it's already in there using this regex pattern:
0 \* \* \* \* my-script\.bash

all clear; pattern was not already present; adding command to crontab hourly:
my-script.bash
```

Comment: If the `$cmd` or `$entry` contains `%` it will trigger unexpected formatting in the `printf` statement. Don't do `printf "$var/n"` but instead use `printf "%s/n" "$var"`

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: This actually works, tested in Bash 4.4.

```
if [[ $(crontab -l | egrep -v "^(#|$)" | grep -q 'some_command'; echo $?) == 1 ]]
then
    printf '%s\n' "$(crontab -l; echo '* * * * * some_command')" | crontab -
fi
```

Comment: (1) Why not say just ``(crontab -l; echo '* * * * * some_command') | crontab -`` and leave out the `printf`?  (2) You don’t need to `echo $?`, and *capture the output from that* to test the exit status from a command.  You could do `crontab -l | egrep -v "^(#|$)" | grep -q 'some_command'` and then (on the next line, or separated by a `;`) `if [ "$?" = 1 ]`.  (Yes, even `$?` should be quoted.)  But why compare to 1?  It’s standard to compare to 0 (e.g.,  `if [ "$?" != 0 ]`.  But then; you don’t need to use `$?` at all; … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … just do `if ! crontab -l | egrep -v "^(#|$)" | grep -q 'some_command'` (… `then`).  (3) And why bother to grep out blank lines?  `grep 'some_command'` isn’t going to match a blank line; why not just say `grep -v "^#" | grep -q 'some_command'`?  But then consider `grep -q '^[^#]*some_command'`.  (Of course you should be sure that `some_command` isn’t blank, or a regular expression that matches anything other than itself.)  (4) @roaima: You know you said `/n` when you meant `\n` in your comment, right?

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' thanks, I keep doing that here on SE; not sure why. I've removed the comment as it seems that at some point I just edited the answer anyway

Answer (score 1):

To add new job from terminal

```
(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "25 2 * * * command/script") | crontab -
```

To modify existing cron job entry from terminal

```
(crontab -l | sed -e 's|old_part_of_job|new_part_of_job|g') | crontab -
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "$(crontab -l 2>&1 ; echo '58 6 16 3 * some_command )" | crontab -
```

TO append to Crontab above command works best for me. It will retain old crontab jobs