# I cannot echo job to root's crontab with sudo - shell hangs

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, cron

I'm currently working on bash script, that will add jobs to root's crontab. I'm trying to achieve it with command:

```
sudo crontab -e -u root | { cat; echo "@reboot /home/$CURRENT_USER/scripts/reboot.sh"; } | crontab -
```

I'm testing this command in shell of Ubuntu Server 18.04 and right after typing password for sudo shell hangs completely. I've tested that several times. Server resources are ok, everything works fine after establishing new ssh connection.

Please help me understand what is wrong with this command and what should I do to make it write something to roots crontab (sudo su doesn't work, because creates new shell, which stops script).

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/348716/116858

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/297374/216907

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`crontab -e` invokes an editor. The output from the editor goes to the `cat` command, but (at best) it's waiting for you to edit the file.

You probably should do something like this

```
job="@reboot /home/$CURRENT_USER/scripts/reboot.sh"
tab="$(crontab -l)"
{ echo "$tab" | grep -vxF -e "$job"; echo "$job"; } | crontab
```

If the snippet isn't already being run as root, change both instances of the verb `crontab` to `sudo crontab -u root`

Comment: Why read into a variable only to `echo` it? And if you want to delete the job in the existing crontab before adding it at the end, use `grep` with `-x` too, and `-e "$job"`, for safety.

Comment: To avoid the possibility of a race. Much like `cat Fred >Fred`. Thank you for the other suggestions

Comment: Most implementations would write the new crontab to a temporary file before moving it into place. In fact, that is what your code could do too if it want to be sure to preserve the integrity of the existing crontab (which `echo` might not do).

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to use crontab to add entries to cron.

Perhaps something like:

```
echo "59 23 * * *  /home/$CURRENT_USER/scripts/reboot.sh" | sudo tee -a /var/spool/cron/root
```

cron will automatically pick up the change.

A users crontab file is just a standard text file. Manipulate it as needed and cron will pick up the changes.

Comment: Why _not_ use the defined interface (`crontab`)? Your code won't work unless you're already running as root

Comment: yes, it doesn't work:                                                                             `and01admin@snd01pc04:~$ sudo echo "59 23 * * *  /home/$CURRENT_USER/scripts/reboot.sh" >> /var/spool/cron/root
-bash: /var/spool/cron/root: Permission denied`

Comment: sorry about that - I forgot about the wonkiness of sudo and redirects.  I changed the command in my answer.  Give it a try.