# task with cronjob threw script

Tags: linux, scripting, cron, upgrade

i am trying to write a script that will download, enable and add task with cron
and then add auto update and upgrade task to the machine.

what i have until now is

```
sudo apt install cron
sudo systemctl enable cron
```

until here all good
then i add (after a research, the following commands)

```
<(crontab -l) <(echo '50 19 * * * sudo apt update -y') | crontab -
<(crontab -l) <(echo '00 20 * * * sudo apt upgrade -y') | crontab -
```

and when i check the file `crontab -l`

i see that the script did write the task like it should,
but its not runing (i tried to run an apt install every min to see if its working)

but when i write the this command `50 19 * * 3 root sudo apt update -y` with nano on that file `/etc/crontab` it worked

i tried to add root permeation on `crontab -e`
but still not working

any solution?

is there is a way to add text line with script to `/etc/crontab` ? ( i couldn't find a way on line)

thanks you all

Comment: You need a command to concatenate `<(crontab -l)` and `<(echo ...)`, and then feed that into cron using... some incantation of the crontab command.

Comment: hey i will be happy if you can explain a lite bit more if you can

Comment: Related - [Add something to crontab programmatically (over ssh)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/297412/100397). Ignore the "over ssh" part for your situation here

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on one line by setting your editor to `ed`.

```
printf "a\n50 19 * * * sudo apt update -y\n.\nw\nQ\n" | EDITOR=ed crontab -e
```

Essentially, append a line to the file with your content, exit edit mode, write, and save.

Answer (score 0):

On any normal system, `cron` should available. So the installation of `cron` and the enablement via `systemctl` should not be required. It, however, makes your script dependent on `systemd` while that dependency is not necessary.

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

USER=root
FILE=input.file.cron
# or get it from the command line arguments

crontab -u $USER -l | grep -v '#--$FILE:$USER' > /tmp/cr-$USER
awk '{printf("%-100s  #--$FILE:$USER\n", $$0) }' $FILE >> /tmp/cr-$USER
crontab -u $USER /tmp/cr-$USER
rm -f /tmp/cr-$USER
```