# How to use sed to substitute strings which has "\" in it?

Tags: shell-script, sed

I have a file named **MyFile.txt** with the following contents:

> Username=myusername
>   EncryptedPassword=9k3S+sS3g\=\=

Each time I need to change the username and password I run a shell script. In the shell script I store the save username and password to two variables namely:

> oldusername="myusername"
>   oldpassword="9k3S+sS3g\=\="
>
> newusername="mynewusername"
>
> newpassword="U8djlk+h\=="
>
> sed -i "s/$oldusername/$newusername/g" MyFile.txt
>
> sed -i "s/$oldpassword/$newpassword/g" MyFile.txt

The first sed works properly and replaces the username, however the second sed command doesn't work and the password is not changed in the file. I think it is because of the "\" character present in the variables.

Could someone help me out with this and let me know how to go about it?

Thanks..

Comment: Related: [How to ensure that string interpolated into `sed` substitution escapes all metachars](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129059/how-to-ensure-that-string-interpolated-into-sed-substitution-escapes-all-metac)

Comment: yes.. I have used double quotes when assigning the value to the variable. when i echo it, i get the correct values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid workaround, escape all the backslashes:

```
oldpassword="$(printf "$oldpassword" | sed 's/\\/\\\\/g')"
sed -i "s/$oldpassword/$newpassword/g" MyFile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat MyFile.txt 
Username=myusername
EncryptedPassword=9k3S+sS3g\=\=
$ oldusername="myusername"
$ oldpassword="9k3S+sS3g\=\="
$ newusername="mynewusername"
$ newpassword="U8djlk+h\=="

$ perl -pe "s/\Q$oldusername/q($newusername)/e ; s/\Q$oldpassword/q($newpassword)/e" MyFile.txt
Username=mynewusername
EncryptedPassword=U8djlk+h\==
```

From [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) for `\Q` and `q()`

> Returns the value of EXPR with all the ASCII non-"word" characters
>   backslashed. (That is, all ASCII characters not matching
>   /[A-Za-z_0-9]/ will be preceded by a backslash in the returned string,
>   regardless of any locale settings.) This is the internal function
>   implementing the \Q escape in double-quoted strings

Once result is okay, use `perl -i -pe` for inplace editing, same as `sed`

Answer (score -1):

Have you echo'd the contents of $oldpassword? The backslashes will be missing from $oldpassword,

```
$ oldpassword=9k3S+sS3g\=\=
$ echo $oldpassword
9k3S+sS3g==
```

As such the match will fail.

If you want the backslash characters in there, put single quotes around the value you assign to oldpassword to stop the shell from interpreting them as escape sequences, i.e., make the value a literal string,

```
$ oldpassword='9k3S+sS3g\=\=
```

Comment: This does not work. Have you tried ```echo "$oldpassword"  | sed "s/$oldpassword/XXX/g"```?