# Get the last occurrence of a pattern before another pattern

Tags: text-processing

In a file like this one :

```
...
Pattern2:TheWrongBar
foo 
Pattern2:TheRightBar
foo 
First Pattern
foo
...
```

I need to find the last occurrence of `Pattern2` that is before `First Pattern` which would be in this case `Pattern2:TheRightBar`

My first idea is to get all the remaining file before `First pattern` with :

```
sed -e '/First Pattern/,$d' myfile | tac | grep -m1 "Pattern I need to get"
```

Isn't there a way to optimise this code?

Comment: I am going to try all the solutions and compare their speed, I will let you know my result and accept the answer accordingly

Comment: `sed '/First Pattern/q'` would be better than `sed -e '/First Pattern/,$d'` so `sed` stops reading at the first occurrence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finds the line count of "First Pattern", then uses head to display lines above it, pipes through tac and greps it.

```
head --lines=+"$(grep -nm1 "First Pattern" file | cut -d\: -f1)" file | tac | grep -m1 "Pattern2"
```

Eg.

```
head --lines=+6 file | tac | grep -m1 "Pattern2"
```

---

This is more reliable then using -m 1000000 in grep.
Since speed is important to OP, I checked the run time and it also appears to be faster then all other current answers (on my system)

```
wc -l file
25910209 file

time awk '/Pattern2/ {line=$0; next}; /First Pattern/ {print line; exit}' file
Pattern2:TheRightBar

real  0m2.881s
user  0m2.844s
sys 0m0.036s

time sed '/Pattern2/h;/First Pattern/!d;x;/Pattern2/!d;q' file
Pattern2:TheRightBar

real  0m5.218s
user  0m5.192s
sys 0m0.024s

time (grep -m1 "First Pattern" file -B 10000000 | tac | grep -m1 "Pattern2")

real  0m0.624s
user  0m0.552s
sys 0m0.124s

time (head --lines=+"$(grep -nm1 "First Pattern" file | cut -d\: -f1)" file | tac | grep -m1 "Pattern2")
Pattern2:TheRightBar

real  0m0.586s
user  0m0.528s
sys 0m0.160s
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the improvement, that really bothered me. And this also answers the "how much faster" question. If I have some time I will try to do some more tests. I wonder if sed and awk are really slower no matter what.

Comment: Your solution is actually so much faster than mine. In my case, worst case scenario, I spent 2 secs searching the pattern while your solution took 0,6 secs. Fun fact: worst case scenario, my solution couldn't even find the good result since B wasn't large enough.

Comment: Feel free to examine this url on why grep is fast - https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019310.html . Essentially, "The key to making programs fast is to make them do practically nothing. ;-)" It may help explain why awk and sed are slower, they "do more", which makes them much more flexible - but also slower

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
awk '/Pattern2/ {line=$0; next}; /First Pattern/ {print line; exit}' file.txt
```

- `/Pattern2/ {line=$0; next}`: If the pattern `Pattern2` is matched, saving the line in variable `line`, and going to the next line
- `/First Pattern/ {print line; exit}`: if `First Pattern` is found, printing the variable `line`, and exiting

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt                                                                 
...
Pattern2:TheWrongBar
foo 
Pattern2:TheRightBar
foo 
First Pattern
foo
...

% awk '/Pattern2/ {line=$0; next}; /First Pattern/ {print line; exit}' file.txt
Pattern2:TheRightBar
```

Comment: I tried using that in a script, replacing "First Pattern" with "$myvar" but that didn't work, with a straight value it works well though, do you know why?

Comment: @aze Pass the patterns as variables: `awk -v p1="$myvar" -v p2="Pattern2" '$0 ~ p2 {line=$0; next}; $0 ~ p1 {print line; exit}' file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You could run

```
sed '/PATTERN2/h;/PATTERN1/!d;x;/PATTERN2/!d;q' infile
```

How it works:

```
sed '/PATTERN2/h         # if line matches PATTERN2 save it to hold buffer 
/PATTERN1/!d             # if it doesn't match PATTERN1 delete it
x                        # exchange buffers
/PATTERN2/!d             # if current pattern space doesn't match delete it
q' infile                # quit (auto-printing the current pattern space)
```

This would only exit if there's at least one line matching `PATTERN2` before some line matching `PATTERN1` so with an input like

```
1
2
PATTERN1
PATTERN2--1st
3
PATTERN2--2nd
PATTERN1
...
```

it will print

```
PATTERN2--2nd
```

If you wanted instead to exit on first match of `PATTERN1` regardless, you would run

```
sed -n '/PATTERN2/h;/PATTERN1/!d;x;/PATTERN2/p;q' infile
```

which prints nothing with the above input (this one does exactly what your solution does).

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with "$var" instead of PATTERN1 either.  Any idea on why?

Comment: @aze - variables don't expand inside single quotes, you have to use double quotes e.g. `sed "/PATTERN2/h;/$var/!d;x;/PATTERN2/!d;q" infile` but this also means `$var` doesn't contain reserved characters [(those have to be escaped)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129063)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the most efficient way **in my case** was:

```
grep -m1 "First Pattern" my_file -B 10000000 | tac | grep -m1 "Pattern2"
```

Obviously the `-B` option cannot be used in some examples but `grep` is so much faster than `awk` or `sed` that I went with that solution.
If the value for option `-B` gets higher, the search is way less efficient.

Comment: -B 10000000 (throwing a random number and hoping it works) isn't the right way to go about this. What happens if it occurs 10000001 lines after?

Comment: That's why I didn't chose my own answer as a proper solution but awk and sed are too slow for this to be efficient. I haven't found a way to get the full text before the match with grep.

Comment: looks like you can with head --lines=+n. I updated my answer reflecting this method. Seems to work well

Comment: How much slower is "too slow" ? How many lines in a file (average) ? How did you test the speed of each solution ? Did you drop caches and sync in-between the runs ?