# Print ranges from last occurance of a certain pattern to the first occurrence of another pattern

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

Good morning, this is extremely similar to the question [Grep From the Last Occurrence of a Pattern to Another Pattern](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/331742/grep-from-the-last-occurrence-of-a-pattern-to-another-pattern) (several months old), while adding a little more detail.

I am trying to write a UNIX script for a file with multiple duplicate patterns, followed by the pattern I am looking for. However I do not have 'tac' or 'tail -r' (using the UNIX emulator, MKS Toolkit), and am looking to return the last occurrence of Pattern1 before Pattern2, followed by the data in between Pattern1 and Pattern2, and then Pattern2 also. The Patterns in this case would be 'Condition 1' and 'Condition 2':

output.out:

```
...
Condition 1: A
data1
Condition 1: B
data2
Condition 2: C
data3
Condition 1: D
data4
Condition 1: E
data5
Condition 2: F
...
```

I'd like to write an awk (or sed, but figured awk would be the right tool) script to return:

```
Condition 1: B
data2
Condition 2: C
Condition 1: E
data5
Condition 2: F
```

I figure it's some form of the line below, but I can't get the syntax right:

```
awk '/Condition 1/ {acc = $0;} /,/Condition 2/ {print ?}' output.out
```

Working the '/,/' is where I seem to be having hangups. Was wondering if anyone had any advice, would be much appreciated. Many thanks for any help and time related to this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$ awk 'f{a=a"\n"$0} /Condition 1/{a=$0; f=1} f && /Condition 2/{print a; f=0}' output.out 
Condition 1: B
data2
Condition 2: C
Condition 1: E
data5
Condition 2: F
```

#### How it works

- `f{a=a"\n"$0}`

  If the variable `f` is true (nonzero), then append the current line onto the end of variable `a`.
- `/Condition 1/{a=$0; f=1}`

  If the current line contains `Condition 1`, then set `s` to the current line and set variable `f` to 1.
- `f && /Condition 2/{print a; f=0}`

  If `f` is true and the current line contains `Condition 2`, then print variable `a` and set `f` back to zero.

Comment: Thank you John, much appreciated. Verified that it gave the same (and correct) results as the sed and perl answers. I did not realize that I was so far off with my thinking, and that it would be more detailed with awk than I thought. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of collecting the lines in a is: `awk '/Condition 1/ {f=1}  f {print} /Condition 2/ {f=0}' ` accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: @PaulSinclair It is a subtle point but that would start printing from the _first_ occurrence of `Condition 1`.  The OP wants to print only from the _last_ time that  `Condition 1` occurs before the line containing `Condition 2`.

Comment: True. I missed that. Your solution is indeed the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

### When you want reverse addressing in text processing, use `ex`

It's [POSIX specified](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html), and it's the scriptable form of `vi` (and `vi`'s immediate predecessor)—very flexible.

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/Condition 2/?Condition 1?,.p' | ex output.out
```

This means:

For every line (`g`lobally) matching the pattern "Condition 2", search backward for the immediately preceding instance of "Condition 1" and `p`rint all lines from that line to the current line (`.`) (which is the line with "Condition 2" on it).

Output on provided input is exactly as you describe.

Comment: Thanks Wildcard. When executing this command, it looks like it gives me the same results as the awk sed and perl commands in this thread, but double spaces the results for some reason (in Notepad++). When I try to trim with "sed '/^$/d' file.txt", no effect, so maybe something weird is going on in my environment. This is definitely very helpful though, as it looks like exactly what I was wanting to do.

Comment: @Henry, very probably you have Windows-style line endings.

Answer (score 4):

```
sed 'H;/PATTERN_1/h;/PATTERN_2/!d;x' infile
```

though this assumes that any line that matches `PATTERN_2` is preceded by at least one line matching `PATTERN_1`. For the more general case add another condition to test for `PATTERN_1` presence in the pattern space before printing:

```
sed 'H;/PATTERN_1/h;/PATTERN_2/!d;x;/PATTERN_1/!d' infile
```

Comment: Thank you Don, much appreciated. Verified that it gave the same (and correct) results as the perl and awk answers.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an evil bit of perl:

```
perl -0777 -ne '
    my $c1 = qr/Condition 1/;
    my $c2 = qr/Condition 2/;
    print for map {s/$c2.*?\n\K.*//s; $_}
              grep {/$c2/}
              split /(?=$c1)/ms;
' output.out
```

It:

- reads the entire file (using the `-0777` and `-n` options),
- splits it where Condition 1 appears (`split`),
- filters out paragraphs where Condition 2 does not appear (`grep`),
- then removes from each interesting paragraph any lines following the Condition 2 line (`map`).

Comment: Thank you Glenn, much appreciated. Verified that it gave the same (and correct) results as the sed and awk answers.