# print lines before one pattern until a new pattern is found

Tags: sed, grep

First it should grep for Pattern_A, then print all lines before Pattern_A until Pattern_B is found(so basically it should search backwards)

`line1
   line2
   line3
   line4
   Pattern_B
   line5
   line6
   line7
   line8
   Pattern_A
   line9
   line10
   line11
   Pattern_B
   line12
   line13
   line14
   line15
   Pattern_A
   line16
   line17
   ....
   ....
   ....`

I want the output to be like this:

`Pattern_B
   line5
   line6
   line7
   line8
   Pattern_A
   Pattern_B
   line12
   line13
   line14
   line15
   Pattern_A`

Comment: See also [Print ranges from last occurance of a certain pattern to the first occurrence of another pattern](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/406109/22142)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I hear "do something backwards", I think: reverse the input then do that something "normally", then reverse the results:

```
tac file | sed -n '/Pattern_A/,/Pattern_B/p' | tac
```

However in this case, the same results occur from "search from pattern B to pattern A"

```
sed -n '/Pattern_B/,/Pattern_A/p' file
```