# Edit /etc/lvm/lvm.conf and add a new global filter

Tags: text-processing, sed

I want to replace the below string with new string in file `test.cfg`.
There is only 1 occurrence of this string in the entire file.

Line in the `test.cfg` file where this string is present:

```
global_filter = [ "a|^/dev/sdaa$|", "r/.*/" ]
```

String to be replaced is: `'"a|^/dev/sdaa$|", "r/.*/"'`

New string to be added is: `'"a|^/dev/sdbb$|"'`

I have the string to be replaced in `$oldValue` variable and the new string in `$newValue` variable.

After replacement inline, the line should look like

```
global_filter = [ "a|^/dev/sdaa$|", "a|^/dev/sdbb$|", "r/.*/" ].
```

I have tried all possible variants of `sed` command, but could not succeed.

Please note that there are multiple spaces between square brackets which should be taken care of.

Kindly help me here.

Comment: Possibly related: [How to ensure that string interpolated into `sed` substitution escapes all metachars](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129059/how-to-ensure-that-string-interpolated-into-sed-substitution-escapes-all-metac)

Comment: 1. This is the second time you're asking this question... 2. Yes, you can add new filters with `sed` (it will be nearly impossible to order by device name though if that's what your example is trying to suggest) but I think there are better tools for this job (that is, tools that read and edit INI files)