# Replace line M in file1 with line N in file2

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

Let `M=3` and `N=4`. I want to replace line `M` in `file1` with line `N` in `file2`. I can replace with a string using `sed`:

```
sed -i '3s/.*/stringToReplace/' file1
```

And I can use `awk` to get line `N` from `file2`

```
awk 'NR==4' "file2"
```

How can I combine these two? If I try

```
sed -i '3s/.*/{awk 'NR==4' "file2"}/' file1
```

then I replace line `M` with literally `{awk 'NR==4' "file2"}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short **sed** approach:

Sample file `f1`:

```
f1 line1
f1 line2
f1 line3
f1 line4
f1 line5
```

---

Sample file `f2`:

```
ID1,value12,value13
ID1,value22,value23
ID1,value32,value33
ID2,/value42/,~value43~
ID3,value52,value53
```

---

The job:

```
sed '3 s/.*/'"$(sed -n '4{ s/\//\\\//g;p;}' f2)"'/;' f1
```

The output:

```
f1 line1
f1 line2
ID2,/value42/,~value43~
f1 line4
f1 line5
```

Comment: won't work for all kinds of data in f2.. for ex: if 4th line was `/4/`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest that is why it is preferable to use `r` command as suggested in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/396450/109046

Comment: @Sundeep, you may check my update

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest that would still fail for other cases like ``4\`` or `4&` etc.. but expanding on what you said earlier, solutions are acceptable according to input formats... my comments are more of a note point which you could add to the answer...

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do this properly so as to handle arbitrary input.
With GNU `sed` and a system that supports `/dev/stdin`:

```
sed -n "${n}{p;q;}" file2 | sed -e "$m{r/dev/stdin" -e 'd;p;}' file1
```

or, slightly shorter<sup>1</sup>:

```
sed $n'!d;q' file2 | sed -e $m'{r /dev/stdin' -e 'd;p;}' file1
```

With any `sed` and a shell that supports process substitution

```
sed '1h;1d;'$((m+1))'x' <(sed ${n}'!d;q' file2) file1
```

which could also be written as

```
sed ${n}'!d;q' file2 | sed '1h;1d;'$((m+1))'x' - file1
```

Basically, one `sed` invocation extracts line `n` from `file2` which is then read by the other `sed` as 1st operand: it saves it into the hold buffer, deletes it and then reads the content of the 2nd operand, namely `file1`, exchanging buffers when on line `m+1` (of the combined input).

With any `sed` that supports reading a script-file via `-f` from `stdin` one could run:

```
sed ${n}'!d;i\
'${m}'c\\
s/\\/&&/g
q' file2 | sed -f - file1
```

here, the 1st `sed` turns line `n` from `file2` into a script-file like

```
${m}c\
line_n_content_here_with_any_backslash_escaped
```

which is then used by the 2nd `sed` to process `file1` (namely *replace line `m` with the following text...*). Any backslashes present in the original text (along with any embedded newlines - but here there's just one line) have to be escaped because when using any of `a\`, `i\` or `c\` to add text

```
<backslash> characters in text shall be removed, and the following character shall be treated literally.
```

With any `sed`, you can use the always-popular `s`ubstitute command [making sure that the string interpolated into `sed` substitution escapes all reserved characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129063) - in this particular case it's just one line so e.g.

```
line=$(sed ${m}'!d;s|[\/&]|\\&|g;q' file2)
```

then substitute:

```
sed ${m}'s/.*/'"$line"'/' file1
```

---

With huge input files you could run:

```
{ head -n $((m-1)); { head -n $((n-1)) >/dev/null; head -n 1; } <file2; head -n 1 >/dev/null; cat; } <file1
```

which does something like this:

```
print (m-1) lines from file1
discard (n-1) lines from file2
print n-th line from file2
discard m-th line from file1
print the remaining lines from file1
```

though some `head`s are dumb and won't [comply with the standards](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html) so this won't work on all setups... but where it does, it trumps `sed`, `awk` and the likes in terms of speed.

---

<sup>1: with some shells you might need to disable history expansion for that `!` to work...

also, `$n` and `$m` don't really need quoting here as they're supposed to be positive integers though it doesn't hurt either</sup>

Comment: from [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands) ... `As a GNU sed extension, the special value /dev/stdin is supported for the file name, which reads the contents of the standard input` I think GNU sed will handle /dev/stdin irrespective of system details

Comment: also perhaps `sed -n "${n}"'{p;q}'` to exit as soon as line is found

Comment: @Sundeep Re: `/dev/stdin`: could be, but my manual doesn't mention that. :) Good point about `{p;q;}`, edited.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$ cat f1
foo
bar
xyz
baz
temp
good
$ cat f2
1
2
3
4
5
6

$ awk -v m=3 -v n=4 'NR==FNR{if(FNR==n) s=$0; next} FNR==m{$0=s} 1' f2 f1
foo
bar
4
baz
temp
good
```

- `NR==FNR` will be true only when first file is being processed
- `if(FNR==n) s=$0` if it is nth line, save to variable
- `next` so that rest of code is not executed as long as first file is processed
- `FNR==m{$0=s}` if it is mth line for second file argument, replace it
- `1` print input record, including any modifications
- Note the order of file input arguments

Can use `if(FNR==n){s=$0;nextfile}` to avoid processing lines after nth line

From [GNU awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Nextfile-Statement.html) - thanks @iruvar

> NOTE: For many years, nextfile was a common extension. In September 2012, it was accepted for inclusion into the POSIX standard. See the Austin Group website.

Comment: [nextfile](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Nextfile-Statement.html) is in POSIX as of Sept 2012

Comment: @iruvar The alternative is "smart" `awk` (GNU `awk`, `mawk`, etc.) vs. old `awk` / `nawk`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix awk with sed. You can use a complete awk solution

file1:

```
 file1 1
 file1 2
 file1 3
 file1 4
```

file2:

```
 file2 1
 file2 2
 file2 3
 file2 4


 awk -v m=3 -v n=4 'NR == FNR { filea[FNR]=$0 } FNR != NR { fileb[FNR]=$0 } END { for (i=1;i<=FNR;i++) { if ( i == m ) { print fileb[n] } else { print filea[i] } } } ' file1 file2
```

Broken down:

```
 NR == FNR { 
            filea[FNR]=$0 
           }
 FNR != NR { 
            fileb[FNR]=$0 
           }
 END { 
       for (i=1;i<=FNR;i++) { 
                               if ( i == m ) { 
                                         print fileb[n] 
                                             } 
                               else { 
                                          print filea[i] 
                                    } 
                            } 
      }
```

We compare NR and FNR to determine records in file1 and file2 (when NR=FNR, we know that we are in the first file) We set up array filea with the records in file1 and fileb with the records in file2. We then loop through all the records in the array filea printing the contents only when the passed parameter m is not equal to 3. If it is, we instead print the subscript of array fileb determined by the passed parameter n