# Replacing *any string* dynamically with POSIX shell

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, posix, variable-substitution

I'm developing a POSIX compliant script in which I want to do a dynamic replace of strings, something like:

```
sed "s/${pattern}/${replace}/g"
```

**Problem**: if the pattern includes the delimiting character, sed returns error, and I want to be able to use all possible characters.

---

1. **Attempt** (with regex): using a non printable delimiter character:

   ( *Edited to [correct](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397916/replacing-any-string-dynamically-with-posix-shell#comment710563_397916) syntax*)

   ```
   d=$(printf '\1')
   sed "s${d}${pattern}${d}${replace}${d}g"
   ```

   Probably not portable.

---

2. **Attempt** (with regex): if pattern contains a certain delimiter, uses another delimiter

   (*edited: now in POSIX-WAY*):

   ```
   test "${pattern#*$delim}" != "${pattern}" && delim='@'
   sed "s${delim}${pattern}${delim}${replace}${delim}g"
   ```

   Not bad but if the pattern contain both **/ more @** sed would return error.

---

3. **Edited Solution** (without regex): Following [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129059/how-to-ensure-that-string-interpolated-into-sed-substitution-escapes-all-metac), escaping chars related to regular expressions.

   ```
   pattern=$(printf '%s\n' "${pattern}" | sed 's:[][\/.^$*]:\\&:g') 
   replace=$(printf '%s\n' "${replace}" | sed 's:[\/&]:\\&:g;$!s/$/\\/')
   ```

**Is there a better POSIX compliant solution with or without sed?**

Comment: I would use awk

Comment: Replacing a _string_ or _regex_? If the former, you'll want to escape regex metacharacters, too. I'd use one pass to escape all occurrences of `/` (and others?) in the pattern-to-be-matched-against (and its replacement); then that sed command is sufficient. Unless of course the pattern-to-be-matched-against contains newlines. If, on the other hand, you care only about fixed strings, Pascal strings (i.e. those with a length prefix) and some extremely simple C code can get you what you want

Comment: See also `case pattern in (*"$delim"*) ;; (*) delim=@; esac`. Note that "Solution 3" is POSIX. Does that not work for you?

Comment: Okay I've posix it, thanks for the corrections :-)

Comment: If you want to use character with code 1 as delimiter, POSIXly, you'd need `c=$(printf '\1'); sed "s$c$pattern$c$replacement${c}g"`, but POSIX doesn't give you any guarantee that that character can be used as delimiter. It could be the newline or slash or @ or backslash character for instance. (not the case in practice though).

Comment: Fox: C is attractive, at the moment I'm with sh but in the future I'll work with POSIX C.

Stéphane and Fox: [Solution 3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129059/how-to-ensure-that-string-interpolated-into-sed-substitution-escapes-all-metac) works and is fine for me because I need to do it in both ways with and without regex, as my question was about strings so it's okay as well. You're right about the non-printable characters, it's nothing portable, I'll look about for some way to do it.