# how to change text string with shell script

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep, cat

**/home/temp.txt**

```
http://url_new_address.com
```

**/home/list.txt**

```
URL http://url_address.com:URL1
URL http://url_address.com:URL2
URL http://url_address.com:URL3
```

How can I replace the line in temp.txt with URL2 in list.txt with shell script ?

after command

**/home/list.txt**

```
URL http://url_address.com:URL1
URL http://url_new_address.com:URL2
URL http://url_address.com:URL3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to don_crissti's suggestion and Stéphane Chazelas [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129063/237982) I have come up with the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

lhs=':URL2'
rhs="URL $(cat temp.txt):URL2"
escaped_lhs=$(printf '%s\n' "$lhs" | sed 's:[][\/.^$*]:\\&:g')
escaped_rhs=$(printf '%s\n' "$rhs" | sed 's:[\/&]:\\&:g;$!s/$/\\/')

sed "s/.*$escaped_lhs/$escaped_rhs/" list.txt
```

This will find any line containing ending in `:URL2` and replace it with:

```
URL http://url_new_address.com:URL2
```