# Defining shell variables

Tags: linux, sed

We have problem defining variables between two shell scripts, basically what we want to do is run `./get_variables.sh`, and fill in the details for "Enter the domain: " and "Enter the vestacp password:" then get the details as variables in `vestacp.sh`

`get_variables.sh` content

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Enter the domain: "
read $domain
echo "Enter the vestacp password:"
read $rvp


/root/vestacp.sh $domain $rvp
```

and

`vestacp.sh` content

```
sed -i s/VAR1/$domain/g config.php
sed -i s/VAR2/$rvp/g config.php
```

`config.php` file content

```
VAR1
VAR2
```

VAR1 and VAR2 should be replaced by the data that we enter when running ./get_variables.sh using sed on vestacp.sh

The problem that we are getting just an empty `config.php` after running `./get_variables.sh`

Comment: Yes, and? What did you try, what did you expect to happen, what did actually happen? (Hint: you probably want to *source* `./get_variables.sh` with `. ./get_variables.sh`, not *run* it.)

Comment: why are you doing `read $domain` and not `read domain` ?

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net will help with the typical shell errors

Comment: Relating: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129059/how-to-ensure-that-string-interpolated-into-sed-substitution-escapes-all-metac

Comment: Also possibly related: [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I see two errors:

- `read variable` should not have a `$`
- variables are not passed by name. The 2nd script is trying to read a variable by the name it was called in the 1st script. It can not know what it was called in first script.

Also break your problems down. There is no way that anyone can write a big program, and then run it, and it work. It this case test each script separately. Get then to work, on their own, then get them to work together.

Also use shellcheck to test you scripts. It will find some of the errors. You will still have to test it. `sudo apt-get install shellcheck` to install on Debian.

Comment: It's working thanks, The problem was $ before variables, removed them all, the script is working now