# Sed in not honoring the $ address char when i try to only match last occurrence from within a script

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

I have created a simple script that i want to use to rename files based on a pattern.

The script uses find and sed to do its work

Everything is basically working, except when I use the $ to tell sed to only match the last occurrence it fails to match anything, so no renaming is performed. If I remove the $ renaming works but all occurrences are renamed which is not what I want, I specifically want to target the last occurrence.

I've followed the docs, tutorials on youtube, searched stack overflow, stack exchange, etc, non of the things i have found work or are even that relevant to my issue, which specifically is tied to the $ address char not working for me.

I've tested the script below, it demonstrates using sed with and without $ char so you can see the issue im having. The logic is organized into 2 functions, searchReplace() and searchReplaceLastMatchOnly().
The searchReplaceLastMatchOnly() function is what I need working, but it fails to match anything.

My test dir is structured as follows:

```
./bar
./bar/baz
./bar/foobar.txt 
./bar/baz/foobar.txt
```

Running script in test dir as follows:

```
./script.sh -d "." -s "bar" -r "Bar" -p "*.txt" -e "txt"
```

Should change:

```
./bar/foobar.txt to ./bar/fooBar.txt
```

and:

```
./bar/baz/foobar.txt to ./bar/baz/fooBar.txt
```

--- Actual Results ---

Using `searchReplace`:

```
Renaming ./bar/baz/foobar.txt to ./Bar/baz/fooBar.txt

Renaming ./bar/foobar.txt to ./Bar/fooBar.txt
```

Using `searchReplaceLastMatchOnly`:

```
Renaming ./bar/baz/foobar.txt to ./bar/baz/foobar.txt

Renaming ./bar/foobar.txt to ./bar/foobar.txt
```

Here is the complete script:

```
# Search and replace using sed.
# $1 target The string to process
# $2 The string to serach for
# $3 The string that will repalce the search string
# Usage Example:
# result=searchReplace "targetToSearch" "Search" "Replace"
# printf "%s" "$result" # should output "targetToReplace"
function searchReplace() {
  # spaces are set as defaults
  target=${1:- }
  search=${2:- }
  replace=${3:- }
  result="$(printf "%s" "$target" | sed "s/${search}/${replace}/g")"
  printf "%s" "$result"
}

# Prints via printf with wrapping newline(\n) chars.
# Note: If no arguments are supplied, pretty print
#       will simpy print a default string followed by
#       a newline character (\n).
# Usage Exmple:
# txt="Text"
# prettyPrint "$txt"
function prettyPrint() {
  # Set default text to print in case no arguments were passed
  # (at the moment this is an empty string)
  text=${1:-}
  [[ -z $text ]] && printf "\n" || printf "\n%s\n" "$text"
  #
}

# Get option values
while getopts "d:p:s:r:e:" opt; do
  case $opt in
  d) dirPath="$OPTARG" ;;
  p) pattern="$OPTARG" ;;
  s) search="$OPTARG" ;;
  r) replace="$OPTARG" ;;
  e) fileExt="$OPTARG" ;;
  *)
    prettyPrint "Error: Invalid flag $opt"
    exit 1
    ;;
  esac
done

# Defaults #
dirPath=${dirPath:-.}
pattern=${pattern:-*}
search=${search:- }
replace=${replace:- }
fileExt=${fileExt:-txt}

prettyPrint "Using searchReplace:"
find "$dirPath" -type f -name "$pattern" | while IFS= read -r original; do
  modified="$(searchReplace "$original" "$search" "$replace")"
  prettyPrint "Renaming $original to $modified"
  #mv "$original" "$modified" | This is the goal...no using till renaming is working.
done

# The dev directory is structured as follows:
# .
# ./bar/fooBar.txt
# ./bar/baz/fooBar.txt
#
# This script when run as follows:
#
# ./script.sh -d "." -s "bar" -r "Bar" -p "*.txt" -e "txt"
#
# Should rename:
# ./bar/foobar.txt to ./bar/fooBar.txt
#
# and also rename:
# ./bar/baz/foobar.txt to ./bar/baz/fooBar.txt
#
# However when I run this script it renames as follows:
#
# ./bar/baz/foobar.txt to ./Bar/baz/fooBar.txt
#
# ./bar/foobar.txt to ./Bar/fooBar.txt
#
# As you can see the ./bar directory is also renamed to Bar, i just want the last
# occurence of bar to be renamed to Bar.
#
# I tried modifying the sed command in the searchReplace() function
# from sed "s/${search}/${replace}/g" to sed "s/${search}$/${replace}/g"
# as i read that the $ should tell sed to match only the last occurence,
# but it doesn't work.
# Below is the modified searchReplace() function that uses the $
#
function searchReplaceLastMatchOnly() {
  # spaces are set as defaults
  target=${1:- }
  search=${2:- }
  replace=${3:- }
  result="$(printf "%s" "$target" | sed "s/${search}$/${replace}/g")"
  printf "%s" "$result"
}

prettyPrint "Using searchReplaceLastMatchOnly:"
# here it is running
find "$dirPath" -type f -name "$pattern" | while IFS= read -r original; do
  modified="$(searchReplaceLastMatchOnly "$original" "$search" "$replace")"
  prettyPrint "Renaming $original to $modified"
  #mv "$original" "$modified" | This is the goal...no using till renaming is working.
done
```

Comment: Your question would benefit from some formatting. You have formatting tools available when you [edit] the question. See also https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5308 for example.

Comment: Your question could also be reduced to two or three lines.  It's kind of unreasonable to expect anyone to read all that without paying them some fee first.

Comment: this script seems like a convoluted way to avoid learning regular expressions.  and the perl rename command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$` anchor:

> Matches the end of a string without consuming any characters. If multiline mode is used, this will also match immediately before a newline character.

This is different from "last occurence",  since your strings actually end with `txt$` and not `bar$` it does not match.

One way to match only the last occurance would be to use `rev` to reverse your string and only replace the first occurance (of course your replacements would also need to be reversed!)

```
function searchReplaceLastMatchOnly() {
  # spaces are set as defaults
  local target=$(rev <<<"${1:- }")
  local search=$(rev <<<"${2:- }")
  local replace=$(rev <<<"${3:- }")
  local esearch=$(printf '%s\n' "$search" | sed 's:[][\/.^$*]:\\&:g')
  local ereplace=$(printf '%s\n' "$replace" | sed 's:[\/&]:\\&:g;$!s/$/\\/')
  result="$(printf "%s" "$target" | sed "s/${esearch}/${ereplace}/" | rev)"
  printf "%s" "$result"
}
```

Note: the `g` operator has been removed from the `sed` command so only the *first* occurrence is replaced.  Additionally we are [escaping the variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/129059/237982) that will be passed to `sed` to prevent them from being interpreted undesirably.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

To replace only the last match, replace

```
result="$(printf "%s" "$target" | sed "s/${search}$/${replace}/g")
```

with

```
result="$(printf "%s" "$target" | sed "s/\(.*\)${search}/\1${replace}/")"
```

The `$` matches the end of the line and not the last search pattern and you don't need the `g` modifier since there is (at most) one replacement.

The `\(.*\)` is greedy and `sed` matches everything before it finds the last `$search` pattern. And since we don't want to delete this part, we have to include it as `\1` in the replacement.

Notes:

- The script is missing a shebang `#!/bin/bash` in the first line.
- `-e` is not (yet) implemented.
- There are a lot of variables which are only used once. Removing them would make your code much cleaner, e.g. the `searchReplaceLastMatchOnly()` function could be reduced to

  ```
  function searchReplaceLastMatchOnly() {
    printf "%s" "${1:- }" | sed "s/\(.*\)${2:- }/\1${3:- }/"
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your notes. Any advice/feedback is always helpful. Can you explain why i would want to use the -e option, I saw it mentioned in examples and the docs by I'm not clear on why I would need/want it. The docs say -e  will "add the script to the commands to be executed" but i don't really understand what that implies.

Comment: @SeviForeman: He was talking about the `-e` option in your script's `getopts` section that sets the `fileExt` variable.  That is never used in your code.