# Using a file with newlines as input to sed replacement

Tags: sed, newlines

I am writing a script to reformat some files. The details aren't important other than that the content replacing what is there contains newlines. Sed interprets the newlines as terminating the sed command and returns an error. I first tried this in gitbash on Windows, and then on CentOS 7. The below output shows the sed command failing once the newline is in the input file.

```
$ echo foobar > foobar.txt

$ echo foo | sed "s/foo/$(cat foobar.txt)/"
foobar

$ echo barfoo >> foobar.txt

$ cat foobar.txt
foobar
barfoo

$ echo foo | sed "s/foo/$(cat foobar.txt)/"
sed: -e expression #1, char 12: unterminated `s' command
```

I would want the output to be

```
foobar
barfoo
```

Is there an easy way (hacks are fine - this isn't for production) to convert the newlines to `\n` or escape them some other way?

Comment: See [How to ensure that string interpolated into \`sed\` substitution escapes all metachars](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/129059)

Answer (score 1):

```
escaped_file_contents=$(<foobar.txt sed 's:[\/&]:\\&:g;$!s/$/\\/')
sed "s/foo/$escaped_file_contents/g"
```

Beware however that trailing empty lines in `foobar.txt` if any are removed.

See this [similar Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/129059) for details.

Or with `perl`:

```
REPL=$(cat foobar.txt) perl -pe 's/foo/$ENV{REPL}/g'
```

Or getting `perl` to read the contents of `foobar.txt` by itself:

```
perl -pe '
  BEGIN {$/ = undef; $repl = <>; $_ = "\n"; chomp $repl}
  s/foo/$repl/g' foobar.txt -
```

Comment: running your command as is gives me `foobar\ barfoo\ `. But `'s:[\/&]:\\&:g;$!s/$/\\n/'` gives me `foobar\n barfoo\n`, which I can work with. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With Gnu sed you can do as shown :

```
$ echo foo | sed -e 's/foo/cat foobar.txt/e'
```

The thing to note is that sed operates on the complete pattern space when using the s///e command. Also the trailing newlines shall be trimmed.

Or, with Perl :

```
 $ perl -lpe 's/foo/qx(cat foobar.txt)/e'
```

Comment: That's usage of the `e` flag for the `s` command would only work for line that are exactly `foo` (and would call a shell and cat for each of those lines and read the content through a pipe. So you'd want `sed 's/^foo$/cat foobar.txt/e'` but you'd rather  use the standard `r` command in that case.

Comment: The `perl` one will include the trailing newline of `foobar.txt` in the replacement (and will also run `cat` for each occurrence of `foo` being replaced)