# Universal sed command for finding and replacing values

Tags: sed, string

Is there a way to use sed to substitute any string for any other string? Because sed uses a delimiter character for the find and replace expression, I can't figure out a way to write a sed command capable of substituting a string with potentially any character (or all characters) in any path for any other string (which may also contain any character).

Here is an example of what I have that does not work:

```bsh
new_value="foobar"
old_value="baz"
echo "$some_path" | sed -e "s|$old_value|$new_value|"
```

This works unless `$new_value` or `$old_value` contains a pipe, in which case the command is invalid because the substitution syntax is broken by the variables used in the sed expression.

Is there a way to use sed to substitute any string for any other string?

If not, is there a Unix good alternative?

Comment: [this link i believe is wot u want](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129059/how-to-ensure-that-string-interpolated-into-sed-substitution-escapes-all-metac&ved=2ahUKEwiRt4ikyKvmAhWJyDgGHY48DLoQFjAAegQIBxAC&usg=AOvVaw3b1xrncc2_M71CEXm_m87j)

Comment: Thanks @RakeshSharma. You are right. That is what I need. The answers here are not correct. Do you recommend using `|` or `/` as the delimiter in the find and replace command? I figured `|` might be easier as paths will contain `/`.

Answer (score 4):

A simple way around this is to escape everything in your variables before calling `sed`:

```
new_value="foo|bar"
old_value="ba|z"
new_value=$(printf '%q' "$new_value")
old_value=$(printf '%q' "$old_value")
some_path="/path/to/ba|z/file"
```

And then:

```
$ echo "$some_path" | sed -e "s|$old_value|$new_value|"
/path/to/foo|bar/file
```

The trick here is the `printf '%q'`. From `help printf` (showing the help of bash's builtin `printf`):

```
  %q    quote the argument in a way that can be reused as shell input
```

Comment: But we can't do this blindly, for there are some characters that take on special meaning when escaped, like `<`

Comment: @RakeshSharma oh! That's a very good point, I hadn't considered `\>` and `\<`. Those can indeed cause issues.

Comment: `(` `)`also take on special meaning when escaped, they become registers.

Comment: @RakeshSharma true, but that's easier to avoid: just use `sed - E`.

Comment: I m assuming Posix sed. And whatever option we choose, doing an escape of all characters is just not done.

Answer (score 1):

you can use shell paramater substitution to escape the needed char:

```
sed -e "s|${old_value//|/\\|}|${new_value//|/\\|}|"
```

Comment: The same applies to your way as well.

Comment: @RakeshSharma the same what?

Comment: The same incorrect way to escape en masse.

Comment: What if the input on lhs had the string `abc{2}` then the escaping will change the very nature of the regex.

Comment: What are you talking about? I'm only escaping the `|` character.

Comment: The OP wanted any character to be handled and not just the pipe.

Comment: Yes, and any character can be used instead of pipe. I don't think OP wants *all* characters, just *any*. Slashes require extra escaping due to the parameter expansion syntax.