# Match parameter in file and replace only the value after equals character

Tags: sed

on the following example file

```
more ambari-agent.ini
[server]
hostname=AABB
```

we want to match `hostname` word in file and replace only the value after `=` ( equals character )

so we did that

```
VAR=server_100

sed -ire "s/(hostname=)[^=]*$/\$VAR/"  /tmp/ambari-agent.ini
```

but still we have

```
more ambari-agent.ini
[server]
hostname=AABB
```

while expected results should be

```
more ambari-agent.ini
[server]
hostname=server_100
```

where we are wrong ?

Comment: The `-i` option takes an argument, which will be used as a backup suffix. You are using `re` as the backup suffix. This is a typo. You also escape the `$` on your variable, so it's value won't be inserted.

Comment: I must to use the "-" because we want to update the file and not redirect it to other file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
VAR=anything
escaped_VAR=$(
  printf '%s\n' "$VAR" |
    LC_ALL=C sed 's|[/&\\]|\\&|g;$!s/$/\\/'
)

LC_ALL=C sed -E -i -e "s/^(hostname=).*/\1$escaped_VAR/" -- "$the_file"
```

With FreeBSD/macOS `sed`, replace `-i` with `-i ''`.

For both GNU (and NetBSD/OpenBSD which eventually copied GNU instead of FreeBSD) and FreeBSD `sed`, `-i` takes an argument which is the name of the backup extension. With GNU `sed`, the argument is optional and has to be stuck to the `-i` option, while for FreeBSD `sed`, it's required (but passing an empty one also disables keeping the backup copy).

`-ire` is interpreted as `-i` with `re` as argument with both GNU and FreeBSD. `-i -e` is interpreted as `-i` with a `-e` argument with FreeBSD, whilst it's interpreted as a `-i` with no argument followed by the `-e` option with GNU `sed`.

Other notes:

- GNU used `-r` for ERE, BSDs used `-E`. `-E` is a lot better and most implementations have settled on that now including GNU `sed`. That's the one that will be specified by POSIX. Here EREs are not necessary anyway. The only feature that EREs have over BREs is `|` (alternation), the rest is just syntactic differences¹. `sed -i "s/^\(hostname=\).*/\1$escaped_VAR/"` would work just as well.
- `.*` may fail to match until the end of the line if the input contains sequence of bytes not forming valid characters in locales other than `C` (hence the `LC_ALL=C`).
- expanding `$VAR` asis in the code passed to `sed` would amount to a command injection vulnerability if the content was not sanitized and `&`, `\`, `/` and newline escaped. Using `\$VAR` like you did, would just replace with a literal `$VAR`, not the contents of the `$VAR` shell variable.
- doing `s/(hostname=)[^=]*$/$escaped_VAR/` would only replace the `hostname` line if the value (or whatever is to the right of `hostname=` which could also be comments for instance) didn't contain `=`. I don't expect it was intended.
- without the `^`, that would match `hostname=` anywhere in the file. `^` makes sure it's only done for `hostname=` instance that are found at the start of the line. If you want to allow leading whitespace, you can always use `"/^([[:space:]]*hostname...`

---

<sup>¹ POSIX EREs are also missing the back-reference feature of BREs though most ERE implementations now support them as an extension</sup>

Comment: why just not use - sed -ie "s/^hostname=.*/hostname=$VAR/"  /tmp/ambari-agent.ini

Comment: @yael, see edit

Comment: +1 for your hard work

Comment: but still , if the syntax - sed -ie "s/^hostname=.*/hostname=$VAR/" /tmp/ambari-agent.ini  , do the job and this is much more simple , what is your opinion?

Comment: @yael, you still have a command injection vulnerability, and you're saving backups of your file with a `e` appended.

Answer (score -1):

The previous answer also works as a function, I'm just lacking reputation to answer with a comment there.

```bash
VAR=anything
function escape() { printf '%s\n' "$1" | LC_ALL=C sed 's|[+/&\\]|\\&|g;$!s/$/\\/' }
LC_ALL=C sed -E -e "s/^(hostname=).*/\1$(escape $VAR)/" -i -- "$file"
```

Please note that I have amended the `+` character to the escape rule.

This also works nicely with dynamically provided `VAR` or otherwise provided substitution values.

```bash
LC_ALL=C sed -E -e "s/^(> API_SECRET=).*/\1$(escape $(pwgen -n 64 1))/" -i -- diff.patch
VAR="admin"; LC_ALL=C sed -E -e "s/^(+SP_ADMIN_USER=).*/\1$(escape "${VAR}")/" -i diff.patch
```

The command differs from the original example by omitting a possibly redundant `-e` and also `--`.

It's possible to further parametrise this logic with another function, omitting `VAR` altogether.

```bash
function replace() { LC_ALL=C sed -E -e "s/^($(escape "${1}")).*/\1$(escape "${2}")/" -i "${3}" }
replace "+ADMIN_USER=" "admin" diff.patch
```

It could then be used programmatically to replace values after chosen line beginnings.

Comment: Note that the standard function definition syntax is `funcname() <compound-command>`

Comment: If you remove -e then the sed code becomes a non-option argument and you shouldn't have any option after that (though with the GNU implementation of `sed` you can get away with it if there's no POSIXLY_CORRECT variable in the environment)

Comment: Why are you adding backslashes before `+`s? It's not special in the replacement part.

Comment: Note that command substitution removes all trailing newline characters so that `echo -n` is rather pointless.

Comment: I have incorporated the comments regarding function syntax, sed arguments and echo -n.

The escaping of plusses was needed to be able to pass them in the regular expression of the first parameter of the replace function. Else they would have been interpreted as RegExp control characters.

Comment: `+` is not the only regex operator; the characters that need to be escaped on the lhs and rhs are not the same ones. See [How to ensure that string interpolated into \`sed\` substitution escapes all metachars](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/129059) for details.

Comment: I meant the syntax is `funcname() <compound-command>` or `funcname () <compound-command>` without the `function` prefix.