# sed: Substituting text pattern containing backslash

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

I have an issue with `sed` that I have been able to recreate with the following simple example.

Consider the following input file (**input.txt**):

```
C:\A\quick\brown\fox\ jumps over the lazy dog
C:\A\quick\brown\fox\ ran with the hounds
```

I want to generate the following output

```
C:\Animal\ jumps over the lazy dog
C:\Animal\ ran with the hounds
```

I tried to create a simple shell script, using sed, but it is not performing the required substitution.    Here is my script:

```
FROM_PATTERN="C:\A\quick\brown\fox\"
TO_PATTERN="C:\Animal\"

#FROM_PATTERN="C:\\A\\quick\\brown\\fox\\"       # Escaping backslash does not help either
#TO_PATTERN="C:\\Animal\\"       # Escaping backslash does not help either


sed 's/$FROM_PATTERN/$TO_PATTERN/g' input.txt
#sed 's/"$FROM_PATTERN"/"$TO_PATTERN"/g' input.txt       # Quoting the pattern does not help either
```

---

I am running `bash` version `GNU bash, version 4.4.12(3)-release-(x86_64-unknown-cygwin)`

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you please specify what you mean by "it is not performing the required substitution". Does it mean there is no substitution at all, or there is substitution in a different way than expected? If possible, please provide an example for the unwanted result of the `sed` call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\` is special:

- as a quoting operator in the shell, including inside double quotes where it can be used to escape itself,`"`, `$`, `` ` `` and do line continuations.
- as a regexp operator (both for escaping and introducing new operators) on the left-hand (pattern) side of the `s` command in `sed`.
- in the replacement part of the `s` `sed` command where it can escape `&`,  itself and newline (or introduce C-style escape sequences such as `\n` in some `sed` implementations).

Also note that shell parameter expansion is not performed inside single-quoted strings.

So here, you'd want to:

- use single quotes instead of double quotes around the `\` characters
- escape the `\` for both the left hand side and right hand side of the `s` command
- use double quotes in the part where variables must be expanded.

```
from_regexp='C:\\A\\quick\\brown\\fox\\'
escaped_replacement='C:\\Animal\\'
sed "s/$from_regexp/$escaped_replacement/g" < your-file
```

Or you could use `perl` instead of `sed` where you can do substitutions of fixed strings without having to worry about special characters if you do it like:

```
from='C:\A\quick\brown\fox\'
to='C:\Animal\'

FROM=$from TO=$to perl -pe 's/\Q$ENV{FROM}\E/$ENV{TO}/g' < your-file
```

See also [How to ensure that string interpolated into `sed` substitution escapes all metachars](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/129059) to work with arbitrary strings.

Answer (score 0):

This was run on Linux machine, not sure if cygwin's behaviour is the same as with bash on linux.

```
PC1:~> echo 'C:\A\quick\brown\fox\ jumps over the lazy dog' | sed -ne 's|\(C:\\A\).\+\\\+\(.\+\)|\1nimal\2|p'
C:\Animal jumps over the lazy dog

PC1:~> echo 'C:\A\quick\brown\fox\ ran with the hounds' | sed -ne 's|\(C:\\A\).\+\\\+\(.\+\)|\1nimal\2|p'
C:\Animal ran with the hounds
PC1:~>
```

So I used group capturing, reused the 'A', then append 'nimal' after it. And to make things a bit clearer, I used '|' as the substitute separator to avoid too many forward slashes.

Hope it helps.

[image]