# sed parameter substitution with multiline quoted string

Tags: sed, json

### Goals

Replace the text `"scripts: {"` with the following string

```
"scripts": {
    "watch": "tsc -w",
```

in a `json` file.

### Attempts

I created two variables for source and destination strings:

#### First attempt

```
SRC='"scripts": {'
DST='"scripts": {
    "watch": "tsc -w",'
```

And ran the following command:

```
sed "s/$SRC/$DST/" foo.json
```

This has failed.

#### Second attempt

This time I escaped double quotes for the source and destination strings:

```
SRC="\"scripts\": {"
DST="\"scripts\": {
    \"watch\": \"tsc -w\",
    \"dev\": \"nodemon dist/index.js\","
```

And ran the same command as above, which failed.

#### Third and fourth attempts

I tried the variables defined as above with the following command:

```
sed 's/'"$SRC"'/'"$DST"'/' foo.json
```

This has failed.

All these attempts yielded the error

```
unterminated 's' command
```

What has gone wrong?

Comment: Could you show more of your JSON document? `sed` is the wrong tool for working with JSON. Something like `jq` would be better. It looks as if you want to insert a key-value pair in some JSON object.  Where is the `scripts` key located within the JSON document?

Comment: @Kusalananda The `scripts` key is located in the first level of the `json` file. It is `package.json` shipped with `npm init -y`. is using `sed` not feasible in this case?

Comment: [Answered](//stackoverflow.com/q/28664782/4850040) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming your JSON document looks something like

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "other-key": "some value"
  }
}
```

... and you'd like to insert some other key-value pair into the `.scripts` object.  Then you may use `jq` to do this:

```
$ jq '.scripts.watch |= "tsc -w"' file.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "other-key": "some value",
    "watch": "tsc -w"
  }
}
```

or,

```
$ jq '.scripts += { watch: "tsc -w" }' file.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "other-key": "some value",
    "watch": "tsc -w"
  }
}
```

Both of these would *replace* an already existing `.scripts.watch` entry.

Note that the order of the key-value pairs within `.scripts` is not important (as it's not an array).

Redirect the output to a new file if you want to save it.

To add multiple key-value pairs to the same object:

```
$ jq '.scripts += { watch: "tsc -w", dev: "nodemon dist/index.js" }' file.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "other-key": "some value",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "dev": "nodemon dist/index.js"
  }
}
```

In combination with `jo` to create the JSON that needs to be added to the `.scripts` object:

```
$ jq --argjson new "$( jo watch='tsc -w' dev='nodemon dist/index.js' )" '.scripts += $new' file.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "other-key": "some value",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "dev": "nodemon dist/index.js"
  }
}
```

---

`sed` is good for parsing line-oriented text. JSON does not come in newline-delimited records, and `sed` does not know about the quoting and character encoding rules etc. of JSON.  To properly parse and modify a structured data set like this (or XML, or YAML, or even CSV under some circumstances), you should use a proper parser.

As an added benefit of using `jq` in this instance, you get a bit of code that is *easily* modified to suit your needs, and that is equally easy to modify to support a change in the input data structure.

Answer (score 6):

[Kusalananda is absolutely right](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/625820/22222) saying that a dedicated parser is the right tool for the job. However, this can easily be done in `sed` (at least with GNU `sed` which understands `\n`) as well. You were making things more complicated by trying to replace the entire two-line pattern. Instead, just *match* the target string and insert the replacement after it:

```
"scripts": {
```

And then:

```
$ sed '/"scripts": {/s/$/\n    "watch": "tsc -w",/' file
"scripts": {
    "watch": "tsc -w",
```

This means "if this line matches the string `"scripts": {`, then replace the end of the line with a newline (`\n`) followed by     `"watch": "tsc -w",`. Alternatively, you can use the `a` sed command to append text:

```
$ sed '/"scripts": {/a\    "watch": "tsc -w",' file 
"scripts": {
    "watch": "tsc -w",
```

Answer (score 2):

Here, we create a Sed command, but put a newline into it:

> ```sh
> sed "s/$SRC/$DST/" foo.json
> ```

That's invalid, as the newline ends the command.  We need to write `\n` instead of a literal newline.  In some shells (Bash, zsh, others..., but not plain POSIX shell), we can do that using a parameter substitution:

```sh
DST=${DST//$'\n'/\\n}
#        //             replace every
#          $'\n'        newline
#               /       with
#                \\n    \ and n
```

For other replacement strings, we may also need to quote `/`, too:

```sh
DST=${DST//\//\\/}
```

Also, `\` (do that one first) and `&` have special meaning in replacement text and therefore would need replacement.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree that `jq` is the optimum tool to use, this particular task can easily be done using `sed`.   Essentially, the task is to append a line of text after a pattern on the previous line is matched.

```
$ cat example.json
{
   "scripts": {  
      "access_token": "asadasd",
      "expires_in": "3600"
   }
}

$ cat demo.sh
#!/bin/bash

SRC='"scripts": {'
DST='\ \ \ \ \ \ "watch": "tsc -w",'

sed '/'"$SRC"'/a '"$DST"'' example.json

$ ./demo.sh
{
   "scripts": {  
      "watch": "tsc -w",
      "access_token": "asadasd",
      "expires_in": "3600"
   }
}
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `sed` regards all text as `regex`, so we have to escape strings before we plug them into `sed` code. Plus, we need to take care whether the string going in is on the lhs or rhs of an `s///` command, coz the list of BRE chars are different on both sides.

```
s='[[:blank:]]'
srch_str='"scripts": {'
repl_str='"watch": "tsc -w",'

esc_srch_str=$(
  printf '%s\n' "$srch_str" |
  sed -e 's:[][\/.^$*]:\\&:g'
)

esc_repl_str=$(
  printf '%s\n' "$repl_str" |
  sed -e 's:[\/&]:\\&:g'
)

sed -e "
  /^$s*$esc_srch_str\$/G
  s/^\($s*\).*\n/&\1  $esc_repl_str/
" file
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "other-key": "some value"
  }
}
```

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129063/116858

Comment: Sed does *not* "regard all text as regex" - in particular, the substitution text of the `s` command is substitution text.