# My sed command is throwing error sed: -e expression #1, char 22: unknown option to `s'

Tags: linux, sed, regular-expression

I tried below command in my script and got error,

```
sed -i -e 's/\(dataTable\)/$replace \1/' file.txt
```

Error Message,

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 22: unknown option to `s'
```

Please help me in correcting the command to avoid error.

Thanks!

Comment: I can't get that error, not on Linux nor on macOS. Character 22 would also be in the middle of the word `replace`, so it doesn't look like it would be taken as an option to `s`, like the `x` in `s/.../.../x` would. You may want to double-check that's the actual command you used.

Comment: ... I can imagine it happening if you'd used double quotes rather than single quotes, and `$replace` contains a forward slash character (like `replace=some/thing`)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are *actually* using double quotes around your `sed` expression rather than single quotes, or you would not get that error.

I'm also assuming that you are using a string in your `$replace` value that contains a slash (`/`).  When the variable is expanded, its value is injected into the `sed` statement and since it contains a slash, it breaks the syntax for the `s///` command.

You can solve this by changing the delimiter that you use in the `sed` command to some other character that is not present in `$replace`.

If you choose `@`, for example,

```bsh
sed -i -e 's@\(dataTable\)@'"$replace"' \1@' file.txt
```

Note that you will still have issue is your `$replace` string contains the substrings `\x` (where `x` is any digit), or `&` (which would be replaced by the part of the string that matches the expression).  You will have to escape these special strings.

See e.g.

- [How to ensure that string interpolated into `sed` substitution escapes all metachars](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129059)

As a special case, if you plan on replacing a single whole line with new (static) contents, you could do that as follows:

```bsh
printf '%s\n' "$replace" | sed -e '/some pattern/{ r /dev/stdin' -e 'd; }' file.txt
```

This finds the line matching `/some pattern/` and then reads in the replacement text from standard input (from `printf`). It then deletes the old  line.