# ignore whitespace at the beginning of a search pattern

Tags: sed, regular-expression, yaml

This sed expression works, but is there a better way to represent the white space in both the search pattern and replace string?

```bsh
BRANCHTAG=7.17.9-main-5ee3e99d5ff002862d93728d821461033de1186d
PRIOR_VERSION=7.17.4
clear; sed "s/^    newTag: ${PRIOR_VERSION}.*$/    newTag: ${BRANCHTAG}/" kustomization.yaml
```

I cannot just search on newTag as that would replace all newTag strings in the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to allow any number of blanks (spaces or tabs) at the start of the line and that you want to keep these:

```bsh
sed "s/^\([[:blank:]]*newTag:\) $PRIOR_VERSION.*/\1 $BRANCHTAG/" kustomization.yaml
```

This uses a back-reference to insert the matched blanks and the key itself in the replacement part of the `sed` expression.  The new value is then inserted after that.

It is assumed that the value in `$BRANCHTAG` does not contain the character `&`, literal newlines, or the slash or backslash character (these would need to be escaped separately).

It is assumed that the value in `$PRIOR_VERSION` is a regular expression that does not contain slashes.  Since it's interpreted as a regular expression, dots (for example) need to be escaped.

See also [How to ensure that string interpolated into `sed` substitution escapes all metachars](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/129059)

But since you're dealing with a YAML file, it would be safer to use a proper YAML parser, such as `yq` (from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/):

```bsh
yq -y --arg oldval "$PRIOR_VALUE" --arg newval "$BRANCHTAG" \
    'if .newTag == $oldval then .newTag |= $newval else . end' kustomization.yaml
```

This assumes that `newTag` is a top-level key in the YAML document and would replace the key's value with the value passed into `$newval` on the command line as the argument to `--arg` if it's current value is `$oldval`.  This value would additionally be properly quoted and encoded by the `yq` parser (assuming it's a common UTF-8 string).  There is no issue with the values containing newlines, backslashes or other characters that may have been problematic with `sed`.

`yq` can do in-place edits using its `--in-place` (or `-i`) option.

Comment: `[[:blank:]]` usually matches a lot more blank characters than just space or tab, though in a `yaml` file, you're unlikely to find any other ones than space and tab.

Comment: sorry I should have passed in 7.17.4 as a variable

Comment: so yq would be the correct tool to use in this circumstance and editing yaml files?

Comment: @PaulMaxfield In my view, yes. As soon as you deal with files in any structured format, such as YAML, JSON, XML, TOML, etc., line-oriented tools like `sed` can probably do some of the naive editings, but they don't know anything about the restrictions, requirements, and structure that these formats have.  Also, injecting shell variables into GNU `sed` _specifically_ is dangerous, unless you have full control over the contents of those variables.

Comment: @Kusalananda thank you for your help