# Insert contents of file into XML attribute

Tags: bash, sed, xml

I have a text file called `branch.txt`:

```bash
$ cat branch.txt
DEMAND_NAME-CR-1234
DEMAND_NAME-CR-8970
```

Using the above branch name, I have to find and replace some values using a `sed` command:

```bash
branch_name=`(cat /tmp/branch.txt)`
sed -i "s/deploy_branch/$branch_name/g" /tmp/input.file
```

When I run the `sed` command, I get an error like the one below:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 35: unterminated `s' command
```

Expected output:

```xml
<Project description="first-deployment" name="DEMAND_NAME-CR-1234 DEMAND_NAME-CR-8970 " overwrite="true" type="Repository">
      </Project>
```

Input file:

```xml
<Project description="first-deployment" name="deploy_branch" overwrite="true" type="Repository">
      </Project>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us your input file and the expected output. You have two lines in `branch.txt`, which one do you want to use?

Comment: Hi @ terdon, sorry for the trouble, i have updated the input file

Comment: branch name contain a new line character. sed is a line editor, so at every line you have a new command

Comment: Which of the lines in the `branch.txt` file do you want to use, or to put the question differently, what do you want your result to look like?

Comment: Hi @ Kusalanda, i have added my expected output, actually the branch name content should be replaced with where the text contains (deploy_branch)

Comment: See [What characters do I need to escape when using sed in a sh script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33005) and [How to ensure that string interpolated into \`sed\` substitution escapes all metachars](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/129059)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your `sed` command is that `$branch_name` contains an embedded newline character.  This breaks the syntax of the substitution command in `sed` when you inject it into the `sed` editing expression.

---

Using `xmlstarlet` to update the `name` attribute of the document's `Project` root node to be the contents of the `branch.txt` file with each newline replaced by a space:

```bash
xmlstarlet edit \
    --update '/Project/@name' \
    --value "$(paste -s -d ' ' branch.txt)" input.file
```

or, shorter,

```bash
xmlstarlet ed \
    -u '/Project/@name' \
    -v "$(paste -s -d ' ' branch.txt)" input.file
```

The `paste` command in the command substitution reads the `branch.txt` file and replaces each newline, apart from the last, with a space character.  This results in a string used as the new value for the `name` attribute.  If you want to retain the final newline character and convert it into a trailing space (as in your expected output), then use `tr '\n' ' ' <branch.txt` in place of the `paste` command.

The `xmlstarlet` utility is invoked with its `ed` sub-command.  This command *edits* an XML file, and we specify that we'd like to update a particular element via an XPath query matching the attribute.

Would you need to make the change only when the `name` attribute's value is `deploy_branch`, then use the XPath query `/Project/@name[. = "deploy_branch"]` or `/Project[@name = "deploy_branch"]/@name` instead.

The output of the above commands would be

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Project description="first-deployment" name="DEMAND_NAME-CR-1234 DEMAND_NAME-CR-8970" overwrite="true" type="Repository">
      </Project>
```

The `xmlstarlet` tool can be made to make an in-place edit if you give it the `--inplace` (`-L`) option after `ed` or `edit`. You may avoid having the `<?xml ...>` declaration added by using `--omit-decl` (`-O`).

Comment: Thanks for the update, i will try install xmlstarlet in my linux box then i will add above content in my azure pipeline

Comment: Hi @Kusalananda, above xmlstarlet command can able edit the file but not able save the content which is exist in branch.txt

Comment: can you please help me

Comment: @viswa Sorry, I don't understand. If you want to save the modified data back to the same filename, use `xmlstarlet ed --inline` followed by the rest of the command (I mentioned this in the last paragraph of my answer).