# referencing a ${variable} value inside a sed substitution

Tags: shell-script, sed, command-substitution

I am trying to replace a string  within a couple of similar sql scripts.
in my toolbox I have a `for loop` as well as `grep` and `sed` inside a bash script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for efa_instance in efa_bauen_bb efa_bauen_bw
do
        echo ${efa_instance}
        secret=$(grep ${efa_instance}_user efa_secret.csv | cut -d\; -f3)
        echo ${secret}
        echo replacing password for ${efa_instance}
        sed -i 's/<via Mail>/${secret}/' ${efa_instance}.service.sql
done
```

this, however replaces the string `<via Mail>` with literally the string `${secret}` instead of the value stored in the `${secret}` variable.

the components of this work as expected, just trying to use sed to actually replace the  placeholder fails.

Am i ot seing something obvious or is my approach flawed by design.

maybe worth mentioning (just if somebody was tempted to recommend that) ... I have never used awk and have no knowledge ot if whatsoever

Comment: Note that you need to be careful if the variable contains slashes or backslashes (at least) see [How to ensure that string interpolated into `sed` substitution escapes all metachars](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/129059/170373)

Comment: thx, I'll check that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `"` instead of `'`:

```
sed -i "s/<via Mail>/${secret}/" ${efa_instance}.service.sql
```

Comment: great thx. I wasn't aware I was actually that close :-)