How can I include any content in the sed replace command?
I want to be able to handle any type of content stored into the bash variable ${CONTENT}, to be used as sed replacement text into another content, no matter if there are quotation marks, single quotes or other special characters that an HTML file with CSS can have, without needing to create temporary files.
CONTENT=$(cat "${HTML_FILE}")
HTML=$(cat "parent_file.html" | tr -d '\n' | sed -E "s/(<body[^>]*>).*(<\/body>)/\1\n${CONTENT}\n\2/")

But this will error out with an error like:
sed: -e expression #1, char XXX: unterminated `s' command

Is what I'm asking for even possible?

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/129059/377345

Do note that attempting to parse HT/XML data using regular expressions is really, really hard. Not impossible, but also not something you should attempt with relatively naive tools like sed. See What can I do when a regular expression pattern doesn't match anywhere in a string?

Do you really just want to replace everything between the <body> and </body> tags? Or is this just a simplified example for the question and you might need more complex things? Because if that's all you need, it is far easier to do without bringing sed into the equation.

@terdon it's exactly like this in my script. i just want to insert some html content between the body tag, maybe there's an easier way to insert content?

@HarryMcKenzie The Jinja2  templating engine could do that for you, or you could just cat the header, body and footer together, if you keep them separate. It all depends on what you're trying to do.  Editing HTML is not something you'd want to do with a text-manipulation tool (or any tool, actually, it's a presentation format).  Creating HTML is also best done with other tools, but is a somewhat easier problem, again, depending on what it is you're wanting to do.

@Kusalananda Thank you. I got an answer that works so all good hehe. But I'm not sure why somebody would downvote it when it worked perfectly fine.

As the comments pointed out, parsing HTML in general should not be done from bash. There are tools out there such as xq which are dedicated to doing this correctly.
That being said, for your specific example there is a simple solution.
Because in HTML nothing is expected to follow </body>, you can simply delete the original content with sed, then insert your content, plus the ending tag, separately:
CONTENT="$(cat "${HTML_FILE}")"
HEADERS="$(tr -d '\n' <"parent_file.html" | sed -E "s/(<body[^>]*>).*$/\1\n/")"
HTML="${HEADERS}${CONTENT}</body>"

(For the sake of clarity, I kept the content in variables above. HTML can get quite large, so for real life I'd recommend parsing on the fly rather than using intermediary variables.)

Please comment why you disagree with the answer instead of just downvoting. I am sincerely interested in a high quality, useful outcome (and believe it already presents a working solution).

Hi thank you for your answer it works. I gave you an upvote. I don't know who downvoted you sorry.
